# Add Column to External List from Updated External Content Type

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, external-list

We are currently trying to understand the relationship between External Content Types and External Lists within SharePoint 2013.  We have a read-only ECT which we defined based on a SQL Server View.  After creating the ECT and the associated List with multiple views we determined that there were columns which were missing from our SQL View.

I was able to update the Read List and Read Item operations to include the additional columns but I am unable to get those additional columns to be made available to the External List associated with the ECT.

I have tried creating a new List based on the same ECT and it also does not display the new columns.

Is there a method or update that I need to run to allow the new columns to be available to the External List?  If I recreate the ECT it will see the new columns but I am trying to avoid having to re-create the ECT each time this change is necessary.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to make these additional columns show up in an External List.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 2):

After further research, it appears that the column was not displaying in the External List because it was of type Int64.  Apparently those can't be displayed within Sharepoint.

In my SQL View I converted them down to Int32 and they were then able to be displayed within an External List.

The External List then needed to be updated to display the new column.  Before it was converted to an Int32 the column did not show up as an option for the External List to display.